# Battery performance of Bluetooth Low Energy (Beacons)

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon, beacon, google-beacon-platform

Some one could tell me please, if there is a way to get the battery performance by setting different advertising intervals of Kontakt beacons(either set to iBeacons or Eddystone frame format).

If yes, Can you please tell me how can i represent graphically the battery performance against advertising intervals?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what kind of beacon battery Konkat use but i can help you with [this technical report](http://www.aislelabs.com/reports/ibeacon-battery-phones/).

Aislelabs explains how the scan interval could impact on battery drain but also the impact of advertising interval on battery drain.

**Impact of advertising interval on battery drain**

Different beacons have different advertising intervals. A short advertising interval (say 100 msec) by Beacon A versus a longer one (say 500 msec) by Beacon B implies that in one second of scanning, Beacon A will be detected 10 times and Beacon B twice by the phone.

Multiple detection of a beacon within the same scan is desirable as it aids in smoothing the signal readings. These signal readings are critical to assessing the precise distance of the beacon from the phone. At the same, multiple signals mean more work required to process the signals, and hence more battery consumption.

***So as we reduced the advertising interval of the beacon, we noticed modestly higher battery use for our three handsets.***

---

Other researches :  An Analysis of the Accuracy of Bluetooth Low
Energy for Indoor Positioning Applications [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmf25/papers/BLE.pdf)

BLE advertising beacons are particularly attractive to
retailers because of the promise of long battery lives of
many years, and so low maintenance requirements. Long
battery lives are expected to require low radio power
output and/or low beaconing rates. While this does not
affect their use for proximity detection it does affect their
usefulness for providing fingerprint-based positioning
throughout an entire indoor environment.

The beaconing rate affects the battery life of the BLE
beacon, and for most iBeacon purposes will typically be
set to an advertising rate of a few Hertz.